# How to detect backspace/delete was pressed on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

There has been lots of questions on how to detect when a user presses `DELETE` button on a `UITextField`. However, playing around with it I realised it is only possible to trigger an `event/action` to run custom code when there is actually content in the `UITextField`. If the `UITextField` is empty and the user hits `DELETE`, no action will be fired on `iOS`.

I tried the following actions: `Editing Changed`, `Editing Did Begin`, `Editing Did End`, `Value Changes`. Also tried the delegate approach: 
 `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

The task I am looking to achieve is related to having a "type your pin code" screen where a user can type in a 6-digits numeric code gotten from SMS message. Since each `UITextField` represents a digit, once the user hits `DELETE`, the app should clear the `UITextField` just before the current one.

Any ideas whether this is possible on iOS?

Comment: It's much simpler to have one off-screen text field that the user types into. Based on the value in that one text field, you update the onscreen representation with 0 to 6 dots or whatever as needed.

Comment: I like this approach. How would it be?